# Dropdown menu is not displaying in my react hooks in a Navbar component imported in Home page

Tags: react-hooks, tailwind-css, flowbite

In my Navbar, the `About Us` dropdown menu is not displaying in my react hooks web app. Following are my dependencies installed. Could someone please advise what could be the reason here ?

CSB link: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-solomon-s7hyck?file=/public/index.html:571-622

[image]

```
"flowbite": "^1.7.0",
"flowbite-react": "^0.4.11",
"postcss": "^8.4.25",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
```

// Navbar component:

```
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="bg-white border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
            <div className="max-w-screen-xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-4">
                <a href="#" className="flex items-center">
                    <img src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg" className="h-8 mr-3" alt="Flowbite Logo" />
                    <span className="self-center text-2xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">Flowbite</span>
                </a>
                <button data-collapse-toggle="navbar-dropdown" type="button" className="inline-flex items-center p-2 w-10 h-10 justify-center text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" aria-controls="navbar-dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                    <svg className="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 17 14">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M1 1h15M1 7h15M1 13h15" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <div className="hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto" id="navbar-dropdown">
                    <ul className="flex flex-col font-medium p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:mt-0 md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white bg-blue-700 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:text-blue-500 dark:bg-blue-600 md:dark:bg-transparent" aria-current="page">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button id="dropdownNavbarLink" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdownNavbar" className="flex items-center justify-between w-full py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:w-auto dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:focus:text-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">About Us <svg className="w-2.5 h-2.5 ml-2.5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
                                <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4" />
                            </svg></button>

                            <div id="dropdownNavbar" className="z-10 hidden font-normal bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600">
                                <ul className="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400" aria-labelledby="dropdownLargeButton">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="https://flowbite.com/" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">About Rob NDIS</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Our People</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Mission Statment</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div className="py-1">
                                    <a href="#" className="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:text-white">Sign out</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Services</a>
                        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Contact</a>
        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Tailwind Configuration:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
}
```

// Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

const Home = () => {
  return (

     <div className='container'>
        <Navbar/>
        <div className="container mx-auto bg-gray-200 rounded-xl shadow border p-8 m-10">
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center">Welcome to the "Rob NDIS"</h1>
          <p className="text-3xl text-gray-700 font-bold mb-5">
              Welcome!
          </p>
          <p className="text-gray-500 text-lg">
              React and Tailwind CSS in action
          </p>
      </div> 

     </div>
      
    
  );
};

export default Home;
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Can you create a running demo using https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: Yes sure i will create one in 45 minutes

Comment: Could you please check this CSB link: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-solomon-s7hyck?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: Can't run, got error *Path must be a string. Received null*

Comment: sorry I tried to fix that the index.css import issue in CSB, not sur about the reason. But I am not getting that issue in local ...

Comment: Can you try this one please >>> https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-solomon-s7hyck?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: The error is gone, but the HTML elements are messed up

Comment: Fixed that html messed up now, could you please check again >> https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-solomon-s7hyck?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254472/discussion-between-soccerway-and-lin-du).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the dropdown menu is not displaying because of this hidden property in this line.
" className="z-10 hidden flex focus:  font-normal bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600"".
you should handle it when the user clicks, hover or etc on it you should show it in one of these modes.
for more example, you can see: https://flowbite.com/docs/components/dropdowns/
good luck Dear.